# Openshift rhc port forward exception

Tags: ruby, ssh, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to open ports so i access my database remotely from my pc

I am running on Ruby200-x64 and when i try to access port forward
rhc port-forward -a appname

i get the following response/error:

```
Checking available ports ... C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:176:in `malloc': bignum too big to convert into `long' (RangeError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:176:in `malloc_ptr'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:240:in `get_token_information'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:213:in `get_current_user'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:189:in `get_security_attributes_for_user'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:332:in `send_query'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:309:in `send'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:148:in `send_packet'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:165:in `send_and_wait'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:76:in `negotiate!'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:48:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:179:in `agent'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:103:in `each_identity'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:79:in `block in authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:211:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/port_forward.rb:86:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:294:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/runner.rb:421:in `run_active_command'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:72:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/delegates.rb:8:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sort of workaround too, whenever i recieve this error i do the oldest trick in the books, a restart and it works all the times(for now)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but maybe it can help to newcomer.
The solution is, or better say- workaround, to exit the pageant while you port-forward the app. And when done turn it on again if you need to ssh to it.